# Javascript method to split string outside curly braces Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

The original string is like this 
"Hi my name is {dog|cat}.|Hi I have a name.|{Gretings|Hi {dog|cat}} "

How can I get:

1. Hi my name is {dog|cat}.
2. Hi I have a name.
3. {Gretings|Hi {dog|cat}}

Using regular expression?

Comment: Where did `my name is` come from?

Comment: @Jerry: it is the first part of the string you must guess.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I think I would rather start learning how to read minds across the internet =P

Comment: how can i get like this: Hi my name is {dog|cat}.
Hi I have a name.
{Gretings|Hi {dog|cat}}

Comment: neeed to be more clear..

Comment: You can't with a single regex since you have nested curly brackets. To solve this you must split your string on `|` `{` `}`, create a flag you increment on `{` and decrement on `}` and record a result on `|` only if the flag is equal to zero.

Comment: I tried split("|") but it returns array like this ["Hi my name is {dog", "cat}.", "Hi I have a name.", "{Gretings", "Hi {dog", "cat}}"]. I want the return array like this if possible ["Hi my name is {dog| cat}.", "Hi I have a name.", "{Gretings | "Hi {dog | cat}}"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I can't get the question, but do you mean something like this:

```
var str = "Hi my name is {dog|cat}.|Hi I have a name.|{Gretings|Hi {dog|cat}}";
```

`console.info(str.split("|"))` returns an array

```
["Hi my name is {dog", "cat}.", "Hi I have a name.", "{Gretings", "Hi {dog", "cat}}"]
```

but with RegExp?

---- EDIT ----

As a very simple version you can do this way (loosing the fullstop):

```
var str = "Hi my name is {dog|cat}.|Hi I have a name.|{Gretings|Hi {dog|cat}}";

var pattern = /[.][|]/;

var re = new RegExp(pattern);

var result = str.split(re);

//var result = str.split(new RegExp(/[.][|]/)); 

console.info('your result: ', result);
```

Comment: 1. Hi my name is {brandon" 2. "mark}." 3. "Hi I have a name."4. "{Gretings"5. "Hi {mark"6. "there}}"] not like 1. Hi my name is {dog|cat}.
2. Hi I have a name.
3. {Gretings|Hi {dog|cat}}

Comment: I want the return array looks like this if possible, thanks ["Hi my name is {dog| cat}.", "Hi I have a name.", "{Gretings | "Hi {dog | cat}}"]

Comment: Looks perfect, but the problem is, if the sentence will not have period before the symbol "|"?

Comment: Sample like this "Gretings|Hi {dog|cat}".

Answer (score 1):

Since javascript regexes can't deal with nested structures (curly brackets here), you must use an other approach.

Example:

```
var str = "Hi my name is {dog|cat}.|Hi I have a name.|{Gretings|Hi {dog|cat}}";
var parts = str.split(/([{}|])/);
var flag = 0;
var results = Array();
var tmp = '';

for (var i = 0; i<parts.length; i++) {
   switch(parts[i]) {
       case '{': flag++; tmp +=parts[i]; break;
       case '}': (flag)&&flag--; tmp +=parts[i]; break;
       case '|': if (flag==0) {
           results.push(tmp);
           tmp='';
           break; }
       default: tmp +=parts[i]; 
   }
}
results.push(tmp);
console.log(results);
```